# Cocos2D-X Literatue

Tags: android, ios, mobile, cocos2d-x

I want to use Cocos2D-X for my games. So I want to read something about it. But besides poor official documentation I didn't find anything.
Can you give some materials on Cocos2D-X.

If you no something better than Cocod2D-x for Android & iOS development, please let me know.
Tnx!

Comment: UPD: I'm interested in 2D engines only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android programmers in my office chose [LibGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) and [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/) over Cocos2D-X because of the lack of documentation.

I use Cocos2D-iPhone however and do find it's useful, but I also have a lot of documentation for the iPhone version

With regard to comments, other, cross platform options are

- [Unity](http://unity3d.com/) is a 3D games engine.
- [Corona](http://www.anscamobile.com/corona/) is a 2D games engine that uses Lua.
- <strike>The [Particle SDK](http://www.particlecode.com/) is a slightly more general cross-platform solution with a background in games.</strike>

> <sub>Today we announced that Particle Code has been acquired by Appcelerator, makers of the Titanium cross-platform framework.</sub>
>
> <sub>...</sub>
>
> <sub>As of January 1, 2012, [*Particle Code*] will no longer officially support the [*Particle SDK*] platform.</sub>

[<sup>Source</sup>](http://www.particlecode.com/developers/welcome/)

- The [Airplay SDK](http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/) is a C++ framework that lets you develop in either Visual Studio or Xcode.

[<sup>Source</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171128/ios-android-cross-platform-development)

Comment: I want something crossplatform. That's why I've chosen Cocos. Do you know something like it?

Comment: Downvoter: any feedback as to why you downvoted?

Comment: 2 James Webster: If it was reply to me, I can't change any reputation... I have only 1 reputation's point

Comment: @LosYear. No, I realised you weren't the downvoter due to your reputation. AlexTSC - thanks.

Comment: So, If I've got this right Particle SDK is free, but it'll be paid after release? But I'll have some discount

Comment: Ah sorry, I'm outdated, Particle SDK has been taken over. I'll remove that link.

Comment: Yeah it was taken over by titanium

Comment: Is it hard to create game with native SDKs and support two branches?
May be it'll be more easy and effective for game? Sure I'll have problems with updating it in app store and marketplace, but may be it will work more faster?

Comment: What do you think about [Moai](http://getmoai.com/)?

Comment: Tnx. I think, I've found my SDK. I can't Vote Up, that's why only "Thank You!" :)

Comment: =] You're welcome. I'll help you on your way to being able to upvote by upvoting your question. =]