# Open-source cross-platform game engine in Java

Tags: android, objective-c, game-engine

I may be asking for something that doesn't exist yet, however I figured I'd give it a shot.

I'm looking to write some simple 2D educational games. I prefer coding in Java, so I'm looking for an open source engine which I can use that can be used on different mobile devices including Windows, Apple and Android based phones and tablets.

I would be okay with a web based solution, however I've believe Borland's XE environments can compile code to be run as native programs. If there is an open source game engine that you can code in Java that can do something similar, that is what I'm looking for (e.g. for Android have Java code which would compile into an apk, and would also compile into a native program on Apple phones).

I did some search-engine searching and found several questions on Stack Overflow, slightly related, and some other articles as well, but nothing giving me exactly what I am looking for.

References:

1. [iOS / Android cross platform development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171128/ios-android-cross-platform-development)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045477/android-iphone-single-codebase-cross-development
3. http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/05/14/eight-popular-open-source-android-game-engines
4. http://goldenstudios.or.id/products/GTGE/ - This is along the lines
   of what I'm looking for, but I want to be able to code toward mobile
   devices.

I'm an experienced programmer, but new to the game programming world.

Comment: I found the following, which I may use unless someone finds something more exact: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/

Answer (score 0):

I did some research on 2D game engines, as far as I known the java based game engine is LibGDX ( http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/), which is cross platform, and performance is good.
I have not tried on LibGDX to make a game, you can try to make one.