# Cross-platform web development combining HTML5 and native capabilities

Tags: html, mobile, web, native

I am absolutely new to the mobile development and I am puzzled by the following question:

How can I write a cross-platform mobile application with UI on HTML5 (same for all platforms), most of logic in JavaScript and ajax, but keeping some of native capabilities like marketplace and a good offline storage?

Do "hybrid" applications provide what I need? Is it possible to get access from javascript code inside "web page" to the phone native resources?

Could someone suggest an entry point for such kind of work (framework/toolkit)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some frameworks like [Corona SDK](http://coronalabs.com/) or [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/),  which can help you to achieve this. Also take a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171128/ios-android-cross-platform-development) similar post. Another good comparison between such frameworks is available at [Mashable](http://mashable.com/2010/08/11/cross-platform-mobile-development-tools/)