# What's the best practice for developing an App on Android, iPhone and J2ME-based mobile pohones?

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, java-me, cross-platform

Our company has started a new project to develop a mobile App on Android, iPhone and J2ME-based mobile phones. This is really a big project and many new services will be added to this App in future. My #1 concern is coding the same App (business+UI+...) on different platforms. Is there any framework/tool/library/etc to code once and then get the App on these platforms? How can I manage my App easier?

**Edit 1:**

It seems that there are lots of frameworks for my case such as RhoMobile, Appcelerator, PhoneGap, etc. Which of these frameworks fits better to my needs and is more stable and convenient?

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?safe=active&sclient=psy-ab&q=iphone+sdk+datepicker+with+month+and+year&oq=iphone+sdk+datepicker+with+month+a&gs_l=hp.3.1.33i29i30l2.1713603.1728624.2.1730763.40.34.2.4.4.2.470.6950.1j17j15j0j1.34.0....0...1c.1.27.psy-ab..4.47.7430.qfGgcGU5qxc&pbx=1&biw=1599&bih=723&dpr=1&cad=cbv&sei=Z6FPUqLOAsvhrAen04CIDg#q=mobile+cross+platform+sdk&safe=active

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171128/ios-android-cross-platform-development

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045477/android-iphone-single-codebase-cross-development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Phone Gap cross platform mobile application development framework for developing the application. Phone Gap(http://phonegap.com) is having support for all the three platforms(Android, iPhone & J2ME/Symbian) you are looking for. Along with Phone Gap you can use the jQuery mobile framework for your business UI. jQuery mobile will give you native look & feel for your application in each platform.

**Update:**
A detailed framework list could be found on [this wiki page.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_phone_web-based_application_framework)