# Java mobile cross-platform framework

Tags: java, android, ios, cross-platform

I already developed my first swing and spring apps, i was wondering if there are any cross platform frameworks for java mobile (android and IOS) app development, if not what frameworks would u suggest.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS / Android cross platform development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171128/ios-android-cross-platform-development)

Comment: @NO_NAME this very question is focusing on frameworks for the Java language

Comment: @Genti: You can check [Codename](https://www.codenameone.com/) framework. Using this we can build iOS and Android apps using Java as a standard language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 Frameworks that I know of, aimed at game development:

- [PlayN](http://playn.io)
- [LibGDX](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com)