# android and ios development

Tags: android, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android & iOS: How to develop for both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100969/android-ios-how-to-develop-for-both)

I want to develop an application for both android and iOS devices. Is there a way to develop the application once and deploy on both? Or is it a must to develop for each platform separately?

Comment: -Andro Selva yes i have heard of it but i don't have much knowledge about it..

Comment: Then do some research mate.. You'll get everything on the internet.. See [this](http://phonegap.com/) for Phonegap. .

Comment: definitely i have to learn that... I mean to say any more platform which support both development

Comment: check this post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171128/ios-android-cross-platform-development][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171128/ios-android-cross-platform-development

Answer (score 3):

You can develop on some cross platform technology, like phoneGap, RHodes, Titanium, html5 Snecha.
By any of these technologies, you can develop an application for all platforms(Android, blackberry, iPhone, windows).

Comment: OK thnks for your valueable feedback

Answer (score 1):

When I used to develop for both Android and iOS I wrote my code in C++ and then wrote code to pass access iOS and Android independantly.  For most Apps you really only need to be getting the touch points and then displaying the information.  This is not terribly hard to do through C++.

Comment: How we can pass the access independently can you explain a bit