# Is there a good tool that allows a developer to develop both IOS and Android devices?

Tags: android, ios, ide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android & iOS: How to develop for both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100969/android-ios-how-to-develop-for-both)

Basically I am looking for a tool (preferably on windows as I don't currently have a mac) that would allow me to write apps for both android and IOS. I am resonably proficient in java and C# with a little C++ but I haven't looked into the mobile environement yet. Is there an IDE/tool that would allow me to develop both types of apps on one machine?

Comment: This has been asked a couple times: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100969/android-ios-how-to-develop-for-both?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from Monotouch, which I believe uses C#, there are a few others. 
There is Phonegap, which uses HTML5 and jquery mobile. Works well on iOs, not so much on Android.
Then there's Titanium, coding is done mostly in JS. Works great on both, but it's quite hard to use JS to build an interface.

Comment: Is there one that is not quite as expensive as monotouch that uses a programming language (any language is fine I can learn it). I would just like to have one IDE or tool that allows development on both.

Comment: Titanium is free to try, if you want more options you'll have to pay.
http://www.appcelerator.com/plans-pricing

Comment: I am ok with purchasing one, I don't have the 1000 dollars to buy monotouch right now. I will look into Titanium